# Publishing to file system in visual studio 2010 is failing unexplainably

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am getting the following two errors when trying to publish my site to filesystem in visual studio 2010,

Error   14  Copying file obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Areas\Admin\Scripts\homescroller.js to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Areas\Admin\Scripts\homescroller.js failed. Could not find file 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Areas\Admin\Scripts\homescroller.js'.        0   0   MHNHub

Error   1   Copying file obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Areas\Admin\Scripts\homescroller.js to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Areas\Admin\Scripts\homescroller.js failed. Could not find file 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Areas\Admin\Scripts\homescroller.js'.      0   0   MHNHub

Why would this be happening? If I run the site, the homepage running that script file works fine, and I was able to do a publish earlier this afternoon with no troubles. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it wasn't just these two files, but it was everything in the obj\Release. I removed the paths to these files and the rest in obj\release in my .csproj file and the project published successfully.